# Ember.js if date variable has gone over current date

Tags: javascript, date, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to ember.js and was creating a model, with a function. The model itself will hold data on a date, but I was creating another attribute as a boolean value, if the model date has gone over the current date I want the boolean value to represent as false.

It might be easier to understand if I show you an example:

```
title: DS.attr('string'),
date: DS.attr('date'),
live: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue:function () {
    if (date)
})}
```

So I want Live to equal true if date is below current date, I'm not sure
or would this really go in the controller, because this variable will have to be constantly checked

Answer (score 0):

You can define `live` as computed property in model.

```
live: Ember.computed('date',function () {
        //this.get('date') - you will get the date for the current record, and you can do any logic and return the corresponding values.
    })
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, my answer will include `live` property for every record in the model. My answer is not correct  if you want `live` property only for the `Model`